# CSS link inside a div class not taking effect

Tags: css

The following code is intended to apply a font color to a link within a div tag however it does not appear to taking effect.

```
/* Body Content */
div.wrapper {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    a:link {color: #ffffff;};
    a:visited {color: #ffffff;};
    a:active {color: #ffffff;};
    a:hover {color: #ffffff;};
}
```

Comment: You're using nested rules which is not possible by using only CSS. You have to use SASS/LESS for that.

Comment: Try `div.wrapper *{ /*css here*/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS you can't nest rules. It's possible just using preprocessors like SASS, LESS, etc.

The correct ruleset for your example is:

```
div.wrapper {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

div.wrapper a:link {color: #ffffff}
div.wrapper a:visited {color: #ffffff}
div.wrapper a:active {color: #ffffff}
div.wrapper a:hover {color: #ffffff}
```

You can write the same shortly:

```
.wrapper {color: #fff; font-size: 16px; line-height: 25px;}
.wrapper a {color: #fff;} /* when other link's declarations are the same, you don't need to repeat them */
.wrapper a:hover {text-decoration: none;} /* for :link, :active and :focus stays underline, for :hover I set decoration to none */
```

Comment: Thanks. How would this apply if text-decorations are required for the link?

Comment: @Motivated: links are underlined by default. If you want to remove underline for eg. hover, just add this one rule. I updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting, the links aren't underlined by default. I have had to explicit specify the code as `div.wrapper a:link {color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;}`

Comment: @Motivated: you probably remove the underlining, links are underlined by default in all browsers. But sure, if you eg. remove underlining and want to return that to some links, use the declaration as you wrote above in your comment.